# OpenDNS DNS lookup using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a small script that will query our local OpenDNS servers (internal) to see if a name exists.  If the name is not in use I will create a CNAME entry in our IPAM solution.  The latter part of this is complete but I am having trouble doing the lookup.  Anyone have any experience or thoughts on this?

Comment: what have you tried so far? What is exactly your question?

Comment: I am trying to perform a DNS lookup from our internal servers.  I have tried dns.resolve() but I end up with a bunch of errors.  Are there any other ways to perform that lookup?